# Custom Sitecore Microsite Resolver

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

We recently worked with a client to create a series of smaller sites that were composed of the same templates and components being developed for their main flagship site. These microsites needed to conform to a common layout but required the ability to have unique branding in the header as well as unique hostnames or domain names. Setting up a new site in Sitecore is a fairly straightforward process, typically – you create the new home node in the content tree then add a declaration to the web.config. In this particular scenario however, the client did not want to have to make a configuration update to deploy each new microsite – they simply wanted to create the content for it, publish it, and have it available to their audiences immediately.

I have gone through a link (https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/chris-sulham/posts/2015/01/quick-guide.aspx) but found incomplete information.

Comment: And what is you question?

Comment: Take a look at the [Dynamic Sites Manager](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/D/Dynamic_Sites_Manager.aspx?sc_lang=en), it allows you to manage the site definitions from within Sitecore rather than having to set it up in config files.

Comment: Hey @Gaurav - Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The general approach to solve this requirement is to store the site definition data in the Sitecore database as a 'site definition' of some kind. You will then need a processor that will initialize the sites list after the file configs have been read and update site definitions or add to the list.

@jammykam pointed to the Dynamic Sites Manager as an example of this, so you may want to start there.

Since authors typically define these new sites after Sitecore start-up, you also will need some functionality (usually a ribbon button or publishing event handler) that will let you trigger an update of the current site list in application memory with the latest data.